# Can't open json file to blender using python

Tags: python, json, blender

I am using blender on windows, following the tutorial: [Visualize JSON Data in blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aRjInmibSw&t=357s) but I am stuck trying to open the JSON file.

My code (windows):

```
    import json 

    with open('C:\Users\Franktabs\Documents\export.json') as f:
        j = json.load(f)
        print(j)
```

His code(linux):

```
import json

with open('/home/chris/Downalds/tutorial.son') as f:
    j = json.load(f)
    print(j)
```

Error Message:

```
Python:   File "C:\Users\Franktabs\Documents\Json2.blend\My Script", line 3
     with open('C:\Users\Franktabs\Documents\export.json') as f:
                   ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
 location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Solutions Tried:

- Using import bpy
- Using double \
- Using 'r'
- Using utf-8
- Checking the file type is actually .json
- Checking the route and name of the file in properties

Solutions sources from a person with the same problem:
[post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64702314/how-do-you-import-json-files-to-blender),[post2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201011/how-do-you-import-json-files-into-blender)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using backslash in python (not to escape)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380484/using-backslash-in-python-not-to-escape)

Comment: Backslashes inside a string (such as your Windows path) have a special meaning and must be *escaped* to be used literally. See the answers to the question linked above for details/workarounds.

Comment: Change your backward slashes ``\`` to forward slashes `/`.

Comment: @MattDMo Why? `os.path.join` should be used instead.

Comment: @OneCricketeer `os.path.join` is still going to need a base path, which will almost certainly include `\U...`, which is what is triggering the unicode error. Forward slashes are perfectly acceptable in Windows path literals, and OP claimed to have tried ``\\`` and `r` literals (which I doubt were done correctly, as they failed, but that's another topic). It's just something else to try without changing the actual code.

Comment: @MattDMo `pathlib.Path.home()` should return the Users directory, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer I agree, there are lots of things that *could* be done to make this problem go away, I just chose the simplest one.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned `\U` is a unicode escape character, and is likely part of the issue. Without seeing the `\\` usage or `r''` code or error, hard to know what the issues there could be...

This should work for an OS-agnostic solution, assuming you have a Documents directory where the file exists

```
import json
import pathlib

with open(pathlib.Path.home() / 'Documents' / 'export.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```